# What happened to numpy.chararray

Tags: numpy

```
#Input: 
chararr = np.chararray((3, 5))
chararr[:] = 'a'
chararr

#Output: 
chararray([[b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a'],
   [b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a'],
   [b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a', b'a']], 
  dtype='|S1')
```

My question is where does that 'b' come from ... I got this from jupyter notebook and PyCharm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3, the default string type is unicode.  Bytestrings are displayed with the `b` flag.  Notice the `<S1` dtype?  That means bytes, `<U1` is for unicode (that's true for both Py2 and Py3).

`chararray` has a `unicode` parameter.

```
In [161]: A=np.chararray((3,5),unicode=True)
In [162]: A[:]='a'
In [163]: A
Out[163]: 
chararray([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']], 
      dtype='<U1')
```

If I did the same in Py2, I'd be seeing `u'a'`.

Answer (score 3):

The `b` in front the string shows it is a **byte literal**. They are instance of **byte** types instead of **str** type and may only contain ASCII characters.

`str` literals are sequence of Unicode characters (UTF-16 or UTF-32).

`byte` literals are sequence of octets (ASCII).

Don't worry, they are not the part of actual string. See, `b` are not inside the  quotes.

For details go to [python's official website.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3112/)

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: @MaximShen If you feel so, can you make this answer accepted?